# No content displayed in native Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

> [image]

This happens in all questions on all Stack Exchange sites.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: Nexus 6
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (2756745)

Comment: No repro: App Version: 1.0.85, Motorola (MotoG 2nd Gen), Android 6.0.

Comment: Slow/broken internet connection, probably WiFi